# Send value from input element to structural directive?

Tags: angular, angular2-directives

I have an input box with a structural direct attached. I need to send the value of my input box back to my directive. What should my approach be?

I tried-

`<input #inputbox *myDirective myValue=inputbox.value>`

The above is what I want to accomplish. Thanks!

Comment: Why would you want to do that? If you place structural directive in any element It will be hidden from DOM.

Comment: I'm making a validation system for my site. I want to be able to add my validation directive, and access the value of the input so I can validate it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import { Input } from "@angular/core";

@Directive({
  selector: "[myDirective]"
})
export class RoleDirective {

  @Input() myValue: string;
```

in HTML:

```
<input #inputbox *myDirective [myValue]=inputbox.value>
```